# Getting a subset error I did not get two months ago when running logistic regression (svyglm) on survey data (SPSS dataset)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey, r-haven

I re-run script that previously worked with no errors about two months ago.

I used the haven package to upload an (non-public and proprietary) `SPSS dataset` and the survey package to analyze complex survey data.

Now, however, when I run even a simple logistic regression where both variables are dummies (coded 0 for no and 1 for yes)...something like this...

```
f <- read_sav("~/data.sav")
fsd <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=f, weights=~f$weight)
model <- svyglm(exclhlth~male,design=fsd,family=quasibinomial())
```

...I get the following errors:

```
Error: Must subset elements with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `omit`.
ℹ It must be logical, numeric, or character.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/vctrs_error_subscript_type>
Must subset elements with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `omit`.
ℹ It must be logical, numeric, or character.
Backtrace:
 1. survey::svyglm(exclhlth ~ male, design = fsd, family = quasibinomial())
 2. survey:::svyglm.survey.design(...)
 4. survey:::`[.survey.design2`(design, -nas, )
 5. base::`[.data.frame`(x$variables, i, ..1, drop = FALSE)
 7. vctrs:::`[.vctrs_vctr`(xj, i)
 8. vctrs:::vec_index(x, i, ...)
 9. vctrs::vec_slice(x, i)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

I've tried running it where I set male as a factor, and where both are set as factors. I get the same errors.

Since two months ago, I have updated `R`, `Rstudio` and both the haven and survey packages. So, I'm guessing that something changed but I am not sure what to do.

I only started transitioning from `SPSS` to `R` late last year, so I thank you in advance for any guidance and apologize in advance for newbie mistakes!

Comment: I'm Just guessing here as something similar happened with me while using another package after updating to R 4.0. In ```RStudio```, menu ```Tools``` go to ```Global Options``` and then in ```General``` change the R version to an earlier version. Try your R codes again in the older version environment. It worked for me.  I do not think this is a long-term solution but it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: what happens when you coerce your data set to a `f <- data.frame(f)` before running the `svydesign` line?  what are the classes of all of the columns you're using?  `sapply( f[ c( "weight" , "exclhlth" , "male" ) ] , class )` ?

Comment: Thanks, Prasanna and Anthony for taking the time to answer my question. (Anthony, I love your twotorials and asdfree.com!) Prasanna, I will try to use an earlier R version, but am on a Mac, so I need to look into how to do that. Anthony, I get the same error message when I set my data to a data frame before running the design line. The weight is numeric, exclhlth and male are "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double".

Comment: Thank you Prasanna for taking the time to answer my question. The Mac version of [tag:RStudio] does not allow me to change the R version. But, I got [RSwitch](https://rud.is/rswitch/) and was able to switch to R 3.6.3. And, now my R codes indeed work as they did before. Thank you. I am still concerned that it doesn't work for R 4.0. What usually happens in these situations?

Comment: Not sure. If you really care about this problem, may be contact the package authors/maintainers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your problem seems to be that the RStudio data import functions are creating classes that hijack the subscript (`[`) operation. This has happened before, when RStudio switched from creating `data.frame` to `tbl` objects, but  then it was sufficient to use `as.data.frame()` before calling `svydesign()`.

Until a new version of the `survey` package is available, can you try using `foreign::read.spss` instead of `haven::read_sav`?

(Also, if you could come up with a less-confidential example and send it to the maintainer, I'm fairly sure he'd be grateful.)

*Update*:  the issue is that the output of `na.omit` has class `omit`, and some of the variables have class `haven_labelled`, and the subsetting operator for `haven_labelled` is very fussy about the class of its arguments: it has to be plain integer or logical, without a class.

The help for the `labelled` class suggests using `haven::as_factor` or `haven::zap_labels` to coerce these labelled vectors to a standard R class.

*Further update*: I filed a github issue for the `haven` package, which was moved to the `vctrs` package, so this behaviour is likely to be changed.

*Further further update*:  This [has been fixed](https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/pull/1179) in the development version of `vctrs`

Comment: Dr. Lumley, I am deeply honored and very grateful that you took the time to answer my question. I will work on a less-confidential example ASAP.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Lumley! It worked when using `foreign::read.spss` with 2 arguments `use.value.labels = FALSE` and `to.data.frame = TRUE`. And, here is a [Dropbox link to data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/80ad8z3jj8o6p24/NNsubsample.sav?dl=0) I can share. I appreciate all your work on the `survey` package.